# How to get old input with value 0 in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

To redirect back with previous input, it is common to have `return redirect()->back()->withInput();`. Then, to retrieve the previous value for radio button:

```
<input name="question1" value="0" type="radio" id="q1-0" {{ old('question1') == 0?'checked':'' }}/>
<label for="q1-0" class="label-margin">0</label>

<input name="question1" value="1" type="radio" id="q1-1" {{ old('question1') == 1?'checked':'' }}/>
<label for="q1-1" class="label-margin">1</label>

<input name="question1" value="2" type="radio" id="q1-2" {{ old('question1') == 2?'checked':'' }}/>
<label for="q1-2" class="label-margin">2</label>

<input name="question1" value="3" type="radio" id="q1-3" {{ old('question1') == 3?'checked':'' }}/>
<label for="q1-3" class="label-margin">3</label>
```

It works fine except for the one with value 0. When there is no previous input for question 1, `old('question1')` also return 0, making the choice 0 always chosen when return, where I want to keep all choices not chosen.

Is there a way to leave choice 0 not blank when there is no previous input?

Comment: Did you check using `null` instead of `0` ?

Answer (score 2):

try this. :)

```
if (old('input_name') !== null && old('input_name') == 0) {
   // input is satified
}
```

Comment: Can you add some meat to the bone?

Answer (score -1):

You can try by comparing using 3 "`=`" like this : `{{ old('question1') === 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}`.

This will make sure that `old('question1')` is really `0` and not `false` or `null`.

Comment: Have you tested before answer? No, this is not working.

Comment: Can you `dd(old('question1'))` and show us what it returns?

Answer (score -2):

Do like this

```
<?php if( old('question1) == '0'){echo "checked";} ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested before answer? No, this is not working.